# What is advantage of backing up a filesystem by version control software?

Tags: backup, version-control

Version control software seems to be used for backing up project mostly in plain text files.

For backing up a file system, with large amount of files or large size, regular file copying/transferring software such as rsync seems to me more proper?

If not, what is the advantage and disavantage of version control for backing up a file system? How is version control worth more than regular file copying or transferring software?

Comment: Rsync is better than most version control systems at handling arbitrary binary files which can change wildly from revision to revision. There are rsync wrappers like http://backintime.le-web.org/ that do allow versioning by time-stamp and use rsync as a mechanism. BackInTime isn't the only tool in its class, it's merely the one I've used the most.

Comment: This question is probably motivated by a comment I made in chat. Tim, if you have questions about this, you could just ask me directly in chat. Briefly, I said that using distributed version control is a good approach to incremental backups for small files, specially text files. While this is not entirely a replacement for regular backups (version control doesn't cope well with large files; it isn't designed to) it has worked well for me over the years.

Comment: @msw If I was using a VCS to save snapshots of arbitrary files, I'd use git.  It does fine with binary files, and I think will even delta-compress between different versions of a mostly-similar binary file.  It's more space efficient than most VCSes.  So handling binary files isn't the reason that backups and VCS are different things.  You can keep your whole home directory in git if you like, and then you can do backups by pushing commits to a repo on another disk / machine / building / city.  I wouldn't use it for LARGE binary files, though.  Doing the commits locally would be slow.

Answer (score 4):

Version control and backup serve different purposes on a different administration level. In projects you control and manage your code with configuration management and version control systems, and on the systems level the admins (IT-division or local administrators) make backups of every relevant data store (be it home-directories of users, or production data databases, or version control databases of projects). In a private environment this difference may not be that obvious, but once you drop the view that both serve "somewhat the same" purpose of "saving your data" it should become quite obvious. Use your version control in your projects to get reliable and reproducable software configurations, and use backups to get data safety for your systems (to prevent accidental or malicious deletion of data, to have a fallback in case of harddisk crashes, fire incidents, etc.).

Comment: Also, a VCS saves all history back to the beginning.  Any viable backup system drops old backups beyond a certiain age, so including some big files at some point doesn't make your data set permanently bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Using distributed (not centralized) version control is a valid backup strategy which is complementary to the more usual backup approaches. There is much to be said for using both methods simultaneously.

Let us review how standard backups work. Typically, ***all*** the files on a filesystem are copied to some remote location. This is done on some fixed periodic schedule, often using cron. This may include the option of incremental backups, which means some backups may only save diffs against an existing backup. This is usually done to save space and allow for more backups in a given space. If this is the case, then the backup software also has the task of reassembling a chosen backup.

Special mention here to deduplicating backup software like [Borg Backup](https://www.borgbackup.org/) and [Restic](https://restic.net/). This state of the art incremental backup technique tries not to duplicate data, and only stores new, unique data.

PROS:

1. The state of ***all*** the files is saved at some particular
   point in time.
2. No actual work is required on the part of the user, at least
   for completely automated backups, which are the norm.

CONS:

1. The state saved has no relationship to any given file. It is
   just an arbitrary point in time.
2. Earlier versions of files will eventually be lost/discarded in
   practice. In theory one can keep a complete history of all
   backups, but this is rarely done for space reasons. However,
   given the greater efficiency of deduplicating backup software
   and the low and diminishing cost of data storage, nowadays it
   is more feasible to keep all backups.
3. The state of a file at a given moment in time is not saved,
   because of the intrinsic limitations of an automated backup
   strategy that saves filesystem snapshots at regular intervals.
   To put it more concretely, if the filesystem in question was
   destroyed, all the changes since the last backup would be lost.
4. There is no way to know if the backup is functional without
   testing/interacting with it, even though serious backup
   software has options for verification. This can be particularly
   problematic with compressed backups.

Now contrast this to backups using distributed version control (DVCS). There are two major free distributed version control systems as I write this in early 2015, namely Git and Mercurial. I think using proprietary version control software is a bad idea for a number of reasons, so I will ignore the existence of such beasts. There are of course other distributed version control systems in existence, for example [Bzr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bazaar), [Darcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcs), [Monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_%28software%29) and [Fossil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_(software)), but Mercurial and Git account for most use in the DVCS space.

How does one do backups using DVCS? Very simply. Commit to your repository, then push somewhere else, preferably to a remote machine in a different physical location, though an attached USB drive will do in a pinch.

PROS:

1. The saved state of each file is by definition customized and
   particular to each file.
2. The repository keeps a complete snapshot history for each file.
   This is, after all, what version control means.
3. It is possible to save the local state of each file at very
   short intervals, even assuming one is not ready to make a
   proper commit. This can done in Mercurial either using
   [Mercurial Queues extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#See_also), or the
   new [Evolve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EvolveExtension). The details of
   how this is done are outside the scope of this post, but the
   effective workflow is that of very fine-grained temporary
   commits, which can later be amalgamated/refined/adjusted into
   permanent commits. Git has [similar queue features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952857/350713). As far as I know. Git
   has nothing similar to Evolve.
4. Pushing to a remote DVCS is a primitive method of validation
   that your backup/repository on the remote machine is alive and
   kicking. While it is not a 100% guarantee (it is possible to
   push to a corrupted repos) it at least tells you that the
   recent commits you made earlier are still present in the remote
   repository with the right hashes and so forth. The standard
   DVCS's will complain loudly if anything appears amiss in the
   structure of the remote repos.

CONS:

1. Not all files will be saved, only those under version control.
2. It is usually impractical to put files beyond a certain size
   under version control. In the case of Mercurial, one starts
   running into performance problems with files at around the 10-
   20 MB size. There are workarounds/hacks to try to deal with
   this, including [Mercurial's largefiles extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HandlingLargeFiles#Current_Workarounds) as well as the famous [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), by the famous Joey Hess, but these aren't,
   as far as I know, substitutes for a proper backup strategy.
3. The user has to work quite hard in setting up the repository,
   making commits, writing log messages, and possibly merging and
   adjusting temporary commits into permanent commits.

Notice that I have intentionally made the pros and cons of "Standard Backup" and "Backup using DVCS" mirror images of each other. Removing DVCS Con 2 would produce exact mirror images. As I said at the beginning of this post, these strategies are complementary.

Note that DVCS Con 3 isn't really a Con, because a sensible user should be using DVCS anyway, in my opinion.